# How do I mount a light intended for a tube to a flat rack?

Tags: commuter, rack, lighting, taillight

I have a rack like this:
[image]
This works really well for me, for the most part.
Alas, I am mounting my taillight like this:

[image]

So, in the past, I've had some PVC pipe affixed to the side of the thing.  Now, I'm shoving a tube underneath straps as seen above.  Does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: zip tie the pvc pipe to the back of the rack

Comment: Why not mount it to the seatpost? Assuming you can mount it high enough to be visible above whatever you are transporting on the rack.

Answer (score 2):

The light seems to have an elastic bungy/strap to hold it on. Your rack appears to have a flat vertical plate on the back.  The light might just strap over that and keep pointing backward.  That would be the simplest option.

---

As for making something. it depends what tools you have access to.  I have 3D printed light-to-bike adapters for several different lights.

https://www.tinkercad.com/things/0SRvpWOsT1e flashlight/torch to a chainstay on a recumbent

https://www.tinkercad.com/things/hbQZMa0HcQc flashlight/torch between the seat stays on a road bike

Every one is custom to the bike and the light's attachments.

If you don't have access to a printer, then carving an interposer from something like wood can be a suitable substitute.  Paint it to protect from moisture.

---

If aesthetics aren't important to you, one can achieve a lot with excessive quantities of cable ties.  Use black ones for UV resistance.

---

Last resort is to put this light on your seatpost and buy a more-suitable second light to go on the rack.  There's nothing wrong with having several rear lights.